# sql query to concatenate incremental number if the field is not null, else auto increment it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm stuck with problem.

There is a table dbo.t1 and here is the result i want to achieve.

Actual output

```
sitename    country
abc.net       NULL
abc.net       NULL
abc.net      India
abc.net      India
```

Expected Output

```
sitename    country
abc.net       1
abc.net       2
abc.net      India1
abc.net      India2
```

So basically, there are two columns, Sitename and Country whose values have been shown above. The nulls should be replaced by incremental values and the values i.e. 'India' in this case should be replaced by itself + incremental values i.e. 'India1', 'India2' and so on.

Pl feel free to ask for any clarifications.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select t.sitename,
       (coalesce(t.country, '') +
        cast(row_number() over (partition by sitename, country order by sitename) as varchar(255)
       ) as country
from t;
```

Comment: If this answer helped you please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  Accepting an answer rewards the contributor and helps others, with similar problems, to find a working answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach via using the `Row_number` and `Union`

```
select sitename , 
isnull(country,'') + convert(varchar(100)
                    ,row_number() over (
                    partition by sitename order by sitename)
                    ) as country
from #Temp 
where country is  null

union 

select sitename , isnull(country,'') + convert(varchar(100)
                    ,row_number() over (
                    partition by sitename order by sitename)
                    ) as country
from #Temp 
where country is  not null
```

**Result:-**

[image]

Comment: Why you need `UNION` here? Can't you remove both `WHERE` clause and `UNION`??

Comment: @JibinBalachandran the desired result with the `India` value is `India1` not `India3` , so if i ignored `Where` and `Union` the values of `country` will be as next: `1` , `2` , `India3` , `India4` but the desired result is `1` , `2` , `India1` , `India2`